# MySQL Order By With Grades As String But Want Integer

Tags: mysql, casting, sql-order-by

I want to order grades that are a string in the following order.

```
K, 1, 2, 4, .... 12
```

But I keep getting `5, 4, 3, ... 12, K, 1`

The grade column in sims_classroom is VARCHAR(255) and the table is latin1;

I have tried every cast and trick in the book. At the moment I have the following trick by adding 0 to it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT district_get_name_function(sod.parent_id, sod.id)) AS 'district_name', 
        (SELECT school_get_name_function(so.id)) AS 'school_name',
        st.teacher_username,
        st.teacher_first_name,
        st.teacher_last_name,
        c.name as 'classroom_name',
        c.grade,
        c.id,
        d.name AS 'discipline_name',
        d.id AS 'discipline_id',
        lc.name AS 'program_name',
        lc.id AS 'program_id'
    FROM sims_classroom c
.
.
.

    ORDER BY 
            CASE lower(sort_direction) WHEN 'asc' THEN
                CASE lower(sort_order)
                    WHEN 'grade' THEN 
                                 CASE c.grade 
                                    WHEN 'K' THEN 0
                                    ELSE (c.grade + 0)
                                 END
                    WHEN 'teachername' THEN lower(st.teacher_first_name)
                    ELSE c.name
                END
            END ASC,
            CASE lower(sort_direction) WHEN 'desc' THEN
                CASE lower(sort_order)
                    WHEN 'grade' THEN 
                                 CASE c.grade 
                                    WHEN 'K' THEN 10000
                                    ELSE (c.grade + 0)
                                 END
                    WHEN 'teachername' THEN lower(st.teacher_first_name)
                    ELSE c.name
                END
            END DESC
```

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of logic to put in an ORDER BY. Can you post your table structure and expected result set?

Comment: I posted the result set, but there are many tables.

Comment: I tried and tried but I can't reproduce your problem. It works fine for me. Can you post as much information as possible? What about the engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only get it to work doing this.

```
WHEN 'grade' THEN 
                             CASE c.grade 
                                 WHEN 'K' THEN '00'
                                 WHEN '9' THEN '09'
                                 WHEN '8' THEN '08'
                                 WHEN '7' THEN '07'
                                 WHEN '6' THEN '06'
                                 WHEN '5' THEN '05'
                                 WHEN '4' THEN '04'
                                 WHEN '3' THEN '03'
                                 WHEN '2' THEN '02'
                                 WHEN '1-2' THEN '01'
                                 WHEN '1' THEN '01'
                                 ELSE c.grade
                             END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lookup table for the grades. It would have the Grade_Name (i.e. 'K','1','2', etc) and a Grade_Order as an int.

You'd have records like this:

```
Grade_Name    Grade_Order
K             1
1             2
2             3
3             4
```

and so on.

Then you can add that lookup table to your JOIN and ORDER BY Grade_Order.

Comment: That might be a last resort.  Dont want to add a new table.'